# Migration number not taking timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

Recently we moved our application from rails 2.3.11 to rails 3.0.7, after everything was done we saw a weird issue. Whenever we generate a migration, the number is auto incrementing where as we needed migration number in UTC timestamp. Since there are 5 members in our team, its causing very big problem.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `config.active_record.timestamped_migrations = true` in your `config/application.rb`